# Calculate date persons becomes a certain age

Tags: c#, date

I'm trying to calculate the date a person turns 18, taking into account leap years.

One might think that just adding 18 years to a date is enough:

```
birthDay.AddYears(18);
```

But if the birthday is February 29, 2000, this leads to february 28, 2018. I believe the correct answer would have to be March 1, 2018.

I found a way to do it, but I wonder if there isn't a simpler way.

```
birthday.AddDays(-1).AddYears(18).AddDays(1);
```

*I would think an answer to this question would already exist on StackOverflow, but all my searches only turn up questions about calculating age on a specific date.*

*I don't think my question is a duplicate of [Behavior of DateTime.AddYears on leap year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498249) as that one only explains why AddYears works as it does. It does not contain code to perform the calculation.*

*I found a [quora article](https://www.quora.com/If-you-are-born-on-February-29-of-a-leap-year-when-is-your-birthday) stating that the official date you turn 18 is different in New Sealand from the UK.*

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498249/behavior-of-datetime-addyears-on-leap-year

Comment: *Counter example* for your current algorithm: `new DateTime(1998, 3, 1).AddDays(-1).AddYears(18).AddDays(1)`: expected `1 Mar 2016`, actual `29 Feb 2016`

Comment: Have u had a look on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/calculate-age-in-c-sharp) ? Alot of answers are including your problem !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behavior of DateTime.AddYears on leap year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498249/behavior-of-datetime-addyears-on-leap-year)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *hiding* the logic (rounding *up* to `1 Mar` instead of rounding *down* to `28 Feb`) into an *extension method*:

```
public static partial class DateTimeExtensions {
  public static DateTime AddYearsUp(this DateTime value, int amount) {
    // Business as usual: neither days are leap days or both days are leap days
    if (value.Month != 2 || value.Day != 29 || DateTime.IsLeapYear(value.Year + amount))
      return value.AddYears(amount);

    // We want 29 Feb to be turned into 1 Mar (not 28 Feb)
    return new DateTime(value.Year + amount, 3, 1, 
                        value.Hour, value.Minute, value.Second, value.Millisecond);
  }
}
```

Then use the method implemented:

```
var result = birthDay.AddYearsUp(18);
```

Please, notice, that you current logic

```
birthday.AddDays(-1).AddYears(18).AddDays(1);
```

is *not correct*; the counter example is

```
// 1 Mar 1998
var birthday = new DateTime(1998, 3, 1);

// Expected:  1 Mar 2016
// Actual:   29 Feb 2016
var result = birthday.AddDays(-1).AddYears(18).AddDays(1);
```

Comment: Regarding my code being incorrect: I dit perform some tests, but I dit not include one where the birthday is in a non-leap year, while the resulting date is a leap year. Thanks for that.

Comment: @comecme: typical *borders check* procedure: `leap` to `leap`, `leap` to `non-leap`, `non-leap` to `leap` (the case where the counter example was found); if you have archive data to work with (when did *Einstein* turn `18`?) it's reasonable to include `1900` year (which is non-leap one).

Comment: I think I would change your last return statement to `return value.AddYears(amount).AddDays(1)`. Is there a specific reason why you are creating a new DateTime like you do?

Comment: @comecme: the very reason of `new DateTime()..` is that I want to be on the *safe side*: I can't guarantee, say, **C# 8.5, .Net 7.0** will not change the logic (and start returning `1 Mar`). I put down my actulal intention: in *case of doubt* (`28 Feb` or `1 Mar`?) I want `1 Mar`, not "the system solution + 1 day"